# How does header for anonymous request to Azure blob storage look like

Tags: azure, curl, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure and I am trying to use cURL to get the list of items inside my Azure blobe. I have configured anonymous read acces to blobs
[image]

However when I am running this request:
`curl -X GET -H "x-ms-version:2021-08-06" -H "x-ms-date:$(date -Ru | sed 's/\+0000/GMT/')" https://name.blob.core.windows.net/name2` 
I get: `Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header`

I tried to add `"Authorization:Basic"` or `"Authorization:Anonumous"` but that does not work.

I have also tried other way with SAS token URL
[image]

So then my request looks like this:
`curl -X GET -H "x-ms-version:2021-08-06" -H "x-ms-date:$(date -Ru | sed 's/\+0000/GMT/')" 'https://name.blob.core.windows.net/name2?sp=r&st=2022-10-12T19:53:09Z&se=2022-10-13T03:53:09Z&skoid=c49c35ef-99c7-49c5-835b-92418a2ccdb6&sktid=b1404f36-3c1b-42e2-9c8d-1b0066b5ff86&skt=2022-10-12T19:53:09Z&ske=2022-10-13T03:53:09Z&sks=b&skv=2021-06-08&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=token'`

But that gives back:

```
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r
2022-10-12T19:53:09Z
2022-10-13T03:53:09Z
/blob/name/$root
c49c35ef-99c7-49c5-835b-92418a2ccdb6
b1404f36-3c1b-42e2-9c8d-1b0066b5ff86
2022-10-12T19:53:09Z
2022-10-13T03:53:09Z
b
2021-06-08




https
2021-06-08
c






</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

How can I fix both of these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the access level as "Blob", you need to use the full URL of the blob (e.g. `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/blob-name`) to access the blob without any authorization information.

However the URL you are specifying for your `GET` request is `https://name.blob.core.windows.net/name2`. Since the Blob URL does not include the container name, Azure Storage tries to look for the blob in [`$root`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-container#remarks) container. Given that you have set the permissions on a container named `alldatastorage` (based on your screenshot) and not on the `$root` container, you are getting 403 error.

To fix this, all you need to do is use the full URL of the blob. For example, if your blob name is `myfile.txt`, your URL would be `https://name.blob.core.windows.net/alldatastorage/myfile.txt`. You should not get this error in that case.